# Xtext typesafe variable qualifier

Tags: grammar, xtext

I have an xtext grammar for a modelling language that has multiple types of variables. In some cases I want to delimit the type a variable can have.
The current workflow is to just use a VariableQualifier (like in the grammar below) and use a validator to only permit the type I want. Then every time I access the reference I have to explicitly cast it.

Is there a better solution?

```
VariableReference:
    ref=[Variable]
;
VariableQualifier:
    (namespace+=NamespaceReference '.')* element=VariableReference
;
EnumerationReference:
    ref=[Enumeration]
;
EnumerationQualifier:
    (namespace+=NamespaceReference '.')* element=EnumerationReference
;
NamespaceReference:
    ref=[Namespace]
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One general pattern for this sort of problem is to have one generic reference syntactically that points to the abstract super type for all possible targets (common super type of Variable|Enumeration|Namespace).

E.g.:

```
VariableReference:
   ref=[AbstractElement] ({VariableReference.parent=current} '.' ref=[AbstractElement])*;
```

Also note that modeling and referencing namespaces is often not really needed. You can instead use fully qualified names of things.

E.g.

```
VariableReference:
   ref=[AbstractElement|QualifiedName]
```